# git includeIf is not including the file

Tags: git, config

Mac

git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)

Hi all. Been googling this for a while now, I found posts that state I need to add /i and also a trailing / so I did all that with no luck :(

```
[includeIf "getdir/i:~/Documents/workspace/"]
        path = ~/.workgit.conf
[includeIf "getdir/i:~/Documents/workspace/private/"]
        path = ~/.privategit.conf
```

.privategit.conf

```
[user]
        email = myemail@gmail.com
```

.workgit.conf

```
[user]
        email = myworkemail@gmail.com
```

no matter if I am in the workspace or workspace/private
`git config --get-all user.email`
returns nothing

Comment: While this may be an embarrassing mistake, I don't know what's others deem wrong with the question per-se. It's detailed and formatted. Wish this would happen for some questions about more complex subject matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your configuration file has `getdir/i`, which is a misspelling of the correct `gitdir/i` (that is, you have an “e” where you should have an “i”).

If you fix that, it should work as documented.